# Silence MPEG4Writer logging

Tags: android, xamarin, mediarecorder

I see lots of logging as a result of turning on Bugsee video recording on android. It's flooding my log with uninteresting messages, particularly by MPEG4Writer

example:

[MPEG4Writer] Video track source stopping

[MPEG4Writer] Video track source stopped

[MPEG4Writer] Video track stopped. Stop source

[MPEG4Writer] Stopping writer thread

etc...

How can I silence this logging?
Bugsee doesn't provide any help from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Bugsee team member here. You can use console filters to achieve what you want. Refer to [Bugsee for Android](https://docs.bugsee.com/sdk/android/privacy/logs/) docs (or for [Xamarin](https://docs.bugsee.com/sdk/xamarin/privacy/logs/) as the attached label states) for more details. You can use regular expression or just look for substring to filter out all the events that contain "MPEG4Writer".